# Remove Webservice from Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, web-services, jax-ws

I am following a little tutorial for JAX-WS [mkyong - jax-ws](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/)

I have published this little example with the following code on my Windows 7 machine.
But how can I update or remove this webservice?

```
public class HelloWorldPublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove : If you want to remove the web service, just use the `Endpoint.stop()` [(read here)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#stop%28%29) methods for stopping it accept the requests.

Update : Just change the code in the `HelloWorldImpl` class. It will automaticaly call the newly updated code.

`Endpoint.publish()` simply tells the server that the requests in the given URL should be processed using `HelloWorldImpl`

Comment: But if I update the code and run HelloWorldPublisher I get an exception:  Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Comment: Do not need to publish it everytime you update the method.  Each time when you want to update the code. Just update the **HelloWorldImpl** class alone. This should work.

Comment: Hmm, I think I am not capable to think today anymore. Mybe I have to read a little bit more about jax.  Ok, I have added a second method to HelloWorldImpl. But, if I make an update on the wsdl with soap ui, the second method does not appear. So I have to tell someone, that there is a new method. And that is the thing I don't understand at the moment.

Comment: @LStrike The best way is to use a good IDE and try to read on generating Jav code from WSDL using an IDE. Both Eclipse and Netbeans are capable of generating webservice stub from a WSDL file.  See this [thread] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179229/generating-web-service-from-wsdl-file)

Comment: Thanks, will do it at the weekend.