# A tool to generate a Java Webservice based on an existing WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Typically you would be able to generate a CLIENT java class(es) based on a WSDL. However, that's not what I need here.

There is a Webservice that I want to create a proxy for. I need the proxy to be able to expose the exact same WSDL as the Webservice. The proxy will then translate the requests and hand them off to another system. Since I have the WSDL for the Webservice, I figure there may be a tool to generate the skeleton code (Java) for the proxy so that it can satisfy that WSDL. A tool would be handy because of the sheer number of operations this Webservice handles.

Once I have the skeleton code, I can go ahead and start writing the logic for each operation that the WSDL has.

Comment: Doesn't the "logic" you speak of end with the client code you say you do not need generated? What else is a WSDL supposed to do for you? If you are writing something in front of that, that is all on you.

Comment: I want to create a new Webservice that exposes the exact same WSDL. Maybe there is a tool that will work backwords from an existing WSDL and generate the skeleton Java code.

Comment: After another 10 minutes of searching I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179229/generating-web-service-from-wsdl-file. I'll check out some of the answers, maybe I created this question pre-maturely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wsdl2Java tool that is provided by Apache Axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actional WebService proxy by Progress Software:
http://www.progress.com/en/Product-Capabilities/continuous-service-optimization.html

It does exactly what you are asking for. It also allows to register custom action handlers that you can place your java code in. Also it does out of the box XSLT transformations, and call splits (e.g. call one service then turn around and call multiple backend services).

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question but isn't this what any contract-first webservice library does?
I believe Spring WS only supports writing the WSDL first and than generate you java code from that. I prefer Apache CXF myself. It supports both aproaches, java or wsdl first.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html