# How to run a webservice from a wsdl file in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

From a colleague I have received a WSDL file that describes the web service he is offering, and which I am supposed to call from my code. I would now like to do two things:

1) Implement the client

2) Have a stub server that I can use for testing, until I have access to the real server.

What I tried is the following:

```
wsimport -clientjar foo.jar foo.wsdl
```

This gives me a jar file that contains the Datatype that will contain the data to be posted to the web service, and also an ObjectFactory. I guess I will have to use it as follows:

```
 TestDataType testDataType = new TestDataType();
   testDataType.setFoo("foo");
   testDataType.setBar("bar"); 
   ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
   JAXBElement<TestDatatype> request = objectFactory.createTestRequest(testDatatype);
```

Now how do I send this request?

Also a class TestDemoService annotated with `@WebServiceClient` has been generated. How do I run this class?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've created the client. To use this client you need to set the endpoint(if not already set) and call the service using the generated api.

This site should be a good reference.
[Using wsimport](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client/)

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial is very helpful. Can you also generate a server (stub) from the wsdl?

Comment: Seems like this is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179229/generating-web-service-from-wsdl-file