# Calling a method of a web service

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, wsdl

So I have a web service published at location "http://localhost:8080/impl1?wsdl". I created a web application using servlets, and I want to call a method from the web service. This is how my web service class is:

```
package controller;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "controller.Hello")
public class Hello
{
    @WebMethod
    public String abc()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I want to call this method from the service in a servlet like hello.abc(), in order to get the result. Is there any method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a proxy of the Web Service. That will allow you to call its methods from a client. There are many tools that take the wsdl as an input and create a proxy as an output.

Take a look at this question:
[Generating Web Service from WSDL File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179229/generating-web-service-from-wsdl-file)